# Typescript type definition of a mapped Object already define

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript, type-definition

I am working on a project using Typescript. The code works fine. I am just wondering what would be the best practice for the type definition of a mapped Object that has been filtered and aslo defined already. For instance, if I have the following code:

```
const person: Person = {
    name: 'Joe',
    surname: 'Doe',
    age: 30,
    address: [{
        mainAddress: {
            street: "Queen st",
            number: 9,
            building: 'main',
            unit: 5,
        },
        secundaryAddress: {
            street: "King st",
            number: 7,
            house: 'The house'
        }
    }]
}

interface Person {
    name: string
    surname: string
    age: number
    address: [{
        mainAddress: {
            street: string
            number:number
            building: string
            unit: number
        }},
        {
        secundaryAddress: {
            street: string
            number: number
            house: string
        }
    }]
}
const filterPerson = person.address.filter((ad: any) => ad.mainAddress ? true : false)

const mappedAddress = filterPerson.map((m: any) => m.)
```

After I do the filter on the main `Object`. I need to map the result. In this case the `filterPerson.map` works fine with `any` as a type definition, but is there a best way to define `ad` in the filter and `m` in the map or should I write a new interface for both in this case.

The error that pops up if I delete `any` on the filter and I hover on mainAddress of the example is this
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

As you can see the Object in my code is different but the syntax on the example here is the same.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfaro.png

Comment: Leave it off completely and let TypeScript infer it, which it will do properly. Do not use `any`, that defeats the purpose of TypeScript

Comment: Hi @CertainPerformance unfortunately, it gives me an error and it doesn't do it.

Comment: What error? It shouldn't, it's completely valid TypeScript to leave it off

Comment: Hi @CertainPerformance I rewrote the post for more info about my info. Thanks in advance

Comment: You have not shown the error that occurs when you leave off the type annotation entirely (no error should arise, and leaving it off is the right way to do it)

Comment: Your `const person` does not have an array of `address` but instead it's an object.

Comment: Your code should have thrown you an error earlier due to your `person` not being typed correctly. Your interface has `address` as an array, but you defined a plain object. Also consider fixing the spelling - `adress` -> `address`

Comment: Hi @CertainPerformance thanks heaps for your help and suggestions. As I said, it works fine. I am trying to improve my typescript skills with this post. Please see this question I posted earlier for you to see my full interface and object. https://stackoverflow.com/q/73228766/14189254

Comment: The object you defined in your question is not assignable to the interface. Don't ignore error messages and you'll have less trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You give us the below object which has `address` as an object

```js
const person: Person = {
    name: 'Joe',
    surname: 'Doe',
    age: 30,
    address: {
        mainAdress: {
            street: "Queen st",
            number: 9,
            building: 'main',
            unit: 5,
        },
        secundaryAdress: {
            street: "King st",
            number: 7,
            house: 'The house'
        }
    }
}
```

But then give us this as the interface which has `address` as an array of objects.

```js
interface Person {
    name: string
    surname: string
    age: number
    address: [{
        mainAdress: {
            street: string
            number:number
            building: string
            unit: number
        }},
        {
        secundaryAdress: {
            street: string
            number: number
            house: string
        }
    }]
}
```

And then you give us an incomplete filter method:

```js
const mappedAddress = filterPerson.map((m: any) => m.)
```

Please fix your examples

EDIT: Assuming that `address` is actually defined like the below I would create 4 interfaces, one for the main `Person`, 1 for the `Address` and one for each type of `Adress`

```js
    address: [{
        mainAdress: {
            street: "Queen st",
            number: 9,
            building: 'main',
            unit: 5,
        },
        secondaryAdress: {
            street: "King st",
            number: 7,
            house: 'The house'
        }
    }]
```

```js
interface MainAdress {
   street: string;
   number: number;
   building: string;
   unit: number;
}

interface SecondaryAdress {
    street: string;
    number: number;
    house: string;
}

interface Address {
    mainAdress?: MainAdress;
    secondaryAdress?: SecondaryAdress;
}

interface Person {
    name: string
    surname: string
    age: number
    address: Address[];
}
```

And then your `filterPerson` const can be typed as follows:

```js
const filterPerson: Address[] = person.address.filter((ad: (Address)) => ad.mainAdress ? true : false)
```